# Can't find matching index with CouchDB and sort

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-mango

I have the following query:

```
{
   "selector":{
      "lastname":{
         "$regex":"(?i)[cç][oòóôõöø]"
      },
      "firstname":{
         "$gt":null
      },
      "type":"person",
      "owner":{
         "$in":["admin"]
      }
   },"sort":["lastname","firstname"]
}
```

And tried many indexes:

```
{
 "type": "json",
 "def": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "lastname": "asc"
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "type": "json",
 "def": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "lastname": "asc"
   },
   {
    "firstname": "asc"
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "type": "json",
 "def": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "lastname": "asc"
   },
   {
    "firstname": "asc"
   },
   {
    "type": "asc"
   },
   {
    "owner": "asc"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

But none worked. FYI I'm using CouchDB 2.1.0.

I also tried to add `"sort":["lastname","firstname","type","owner"]` to the query. Still getting the warning: `no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using PouchDB directly to my CouchDB server (no sync), if that can help...

Comment: My guess is, the first element in the sort must be in the selector and use an operator that use index( regex doesn't)

Comment: @AlexisCôté I tried to put type in first position in the selector but still getting the warning. I also added type in the sort, didn't help either...

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the index before?

```
this._DB.createIndex({
   index: { fields: ['lastname', 'firstname'] },
   ddoc: "my-index-design-doc"
})
```

And use it in your .find than with
`use_index: 'my-index-design-doc'`  ?

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, bear in mind the consequences in performance that you query will have will be drastic in large databases. Operators $in and $regex will process the whole database in memory, since it does not uses any index —nor can, at least at the latest CouchDB version: 3.0.2.

On the other hand, $eq, $gt — $gte, $lt — $lte will indexes without processing all data. This is where it gets clever.